# Camouflage product id's on website

Tags: php, mysql, mask

I'm currently building a retail e-shop for a jewellery manufacturer which also sells wholesale to other shops and I'm looking for an efficient way to "hide"/"camouflage" the product id's for all products so that other competitors wont be able to see the product's barcodes and find out that the manufacturer is doing direct sales at lower prices.

All products on the website have a 4-5 digit id which is also the name of the products' images, ie for Product #1234 image filename is 1234.jpg

One thought was to add a 3-digit random int before and after the product ID that would make it quite hard for someone to figure out the product id. Another thought would be to reverse the id's or perform some sort of scrambling. This would work fine for all the links within the site and all i'd have to do would be to strip off the first and last 3 digits off the product id's or de-scramble before using in the queries but what can I do when it comes to displaying product images? I don't want visitors to be able to see the filenames, that would completely blow the cover for a ll product id's.

Suggestions and ideas are very welcome.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't allow direct access to your images like that. Instead, use a php wrapper which translates your fake product id to the actual image file and return that.

Ie `http://.../getimage.php?fakeid=1337` which translates that into the actual product id 123 and then `readfile("/path/to/123.png");`

Comment: Good point; you are however invoking the script for every image load - should be easier to only have the script run if the image with fake id doesn't exist, and make a copy with the fake id (so that it's loaded directly next time). Loading an image through PHP is slightly slower than letting the webserver serve it directly.

Comment: @Piskvor: Or even better, add a dedicated image cache in front of it (like Varnish) if performance is a problem.

Answer (score 2):

The products don't need to be identified by barcode - you could use a meaningless identifier for the products, and only look up the barcode when you actually need it. Example:

```
product_barcode | product_identifier 
7310791268002   | deadbeef01234cafe
```

Then, you'd use `deadbeef01234cafe` both for identifying the product in the store, and for the image name.

Comment: Certainly correct, I've already thought of this but my main problem is the product images, i've been given 1500 product images that all follow the products barcodes. Even if i display a different "deadbeef" code for reference, i still need a way to hide the images filenames which is visible from the page source.

Comment: @bikey77: Generate the meaningless identifiers, once, then run a script that renames the files, once. From then on, you can use the new filenames. On upload of new image, repeat for that specific barcode.

Comment: @bikey77. See my answer for images.